# How to fix memory leak multithread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

i have a app i want datagridview refresh each row all 5 sec. my code work well except i have a memory leak i presume all ressource was not released ... but its a loop running thread i dont want dispose it ...

i start my task like this

```
Private Sub Desktop_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim F As String = Main.UserDataFolder & "\Wemine4U\Config\MinerList.wemine"
    If IO.File.Exists(F) = True Then
        Dim NOF2 As Integer = FreeFile()
        Dim texte2 As String
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        FileOpen(NOF2, Main.UserDataFolder & "\Wemine4U\Config\MinerList.wemine", OpenMode.Input, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Shared)
        Do Until EOF(NOF2)
            texte2 = LineInput(NOF2)
            Main.DataMiner.Rows.Add(Split(texte2, Chr(9))(1).ToString, "0" + " C", "0.00", "0.00", "0", "0", "0", "0", "N/D", "N/D", Split(texte2, Chr(9))(3).ToString, "", "", "0")

            Dim updatem As System.Threading.Thread
            updatem = New Thread(AddressOf loadTableMiner)
            updatem.Name = Split(texte2, Chr(9))(1) & Chr(9) & Split(texte2, Chr(9))(3)
            updatem.IsBackground = True
            updatem.Start()

        Loop
        FileClose(NOF2)
    End If
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DataSource
    DataGridView1.Columns(11).Visible = False
    DataGridView1.Columns(12).Visible = False
    DataGridView1.Columns(13).Visible = False


End Sub
```

after i want running in loop the thread like this

```
Private Sub loadTableMiner()

StartLoadTable:

    Dim ip As String = Split(Thread.CurrentThread.Name, Chr(9))(0)
        Dim clientssh As SshClient
        Dim cmd As SshCommand
        Dim tview As String
        Dim ValueSSH As String
        Dim ValueSSHsummary As String
        Dim Accepteds As String
        Dim Rejects As String
        Dim Hwerror As String
        Dim Discarded As String
        Dim ValueTemp As String
        Dim IndexOfTable As Integer
        Dim Type As String = Split(Thread.CurrentThread.Name, Chr(9))(1)
        Dim MS As String
        Dim GH As String
        Dim GHS As String
        Dim ValueGHSDIFF As Decimal
        Dim ValueGHSM
        Dim NBV As Integer
        Dim nbvt As Integer
        Dim TT As String
        Dim NBI As Integer
        Dim ValueGHS
        Dim ValueReboot As Decimal

RestartF:


    Try
        If clientssh Is Nothing Then
            clientssh = New SshClient(ip, "root", "admin")
            clientssh.Connect()
        End If

        If Type = "AntMiner S9" Then
            cmd = clientssh.RunCommand("bmminer-api -o stats")
        End If
        If Type = "AntMiner L3+" Then
            cmd = clientssh.RunCommand("cgminer-api -o stats")
        End If

        ValueSSH = cmd.Result

        If Type = "AntMiner S9" Then
            cmd = clientssh.RunCommand("bmminer-api -o summary")
        End If
        If Type = "AntMiner L3+" Then
            cmd = clientssh.RunCommand("cgminer-api -o summary")
        End If

        ValueSSHsummary = cmd.Result
    Catch ex As Exception
        clientssh.Disconnect()
        clientssh = Nothing

        Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(5000)

        GoTo RestartF

    End Try

        If InStr(ValueSSH, "Connection refused") > 0 Or InStr(ValueSSHsummary, "Connection refused") > 0 Then
            PutDataInTable(IndexOfTable, ip, "0", "0.00", "0.00", "0", "0", "0", "0", "N/D", "Connection refused", Type, "", "", "0")
            clientssh.Disconnect()
        clientssh = Nothing
        Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(5000)

        GoTo RestartF
        End If

        If ValueSSH = "" Or ValueSSHsummary = "" Then
            PutDataInTable(IndexOfTable, ip, "0", "0.00", "0.00", "0", "0", "0", "0", "N/D", "Not Online", Type, "", "", "0")
            clientssh.Disconnect()
        clientssh = Nothing

        Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(5000)

        GoTo RestartF
        Else

            Accepteds = Split(Split(ValueSSHsummary, "Accepted=")(1).ToString, ",")(0)
            Rejects = Split(Split(ValueSSHsummary, "Rejected=")(1).ToString, ",")(0)
            Hwerror = Split(Split(ValueSSHsummary, "Hardware Errors=")(1).ToString, ",")(0)
            Discarded = Split(Split(ValueSSHsummary, "Discarded=")(1).ToString, ",")(0)

            ValueTemp = Split(Split(ValueSSH, ",")(33).ToString, "=")(1)
            NBV = CountCharacter(ValueSSH, ",")
            nbvt = 0
            Do Until nbvt = NBV
                TT = Split(ValueSSH, ",")(nbvt).ToString
                NBI = InStr(TT, "temp")
                If NBI > 0 Then
                    tview = Split(Split(ValueSSH, ",")(nbvt), "=")(1)
                    If CInt(tview) > CInt(ValueTemp) Then
                        ValueTemp = Split(Split(ValueSSH, ",")(nbvt).ToString, "=")(1)
                    End If

                End If
                nbvt = nbvt + 1
            Loop

            If 20 > ValueTemp Or ValueTemp > 100 Then
                SSHReboot(ip)
                PutDataInTable(IndexOfTable, ip, "0", "0.00", "0.00", "0", "0", "0", "0", "N/D", "Rebooting Temp", Type, "", "", "0")
                clientssh.Disconnect()
            clientssh = Nothing

            Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(5000)

            GoTo RestartF

            End If

            If Language = "fr-CA" Then
                If Type = "AntMiner S9" Then
                    ValueGHS = CDec(Replace(Split(Split(ValueSSH, ",")(14).ToString, "=")(1), ".", ",")) / 1000
                End If
                If Type = "AntMiner L3+" Then
                    ValueGHS = CDec(Replace(Split(Split(ValueSSH, ",")(14).ToString, "=")(1), ".", ","))
                End If
            Else
                If Type = "AntMiner S9" Then
                    ValueGHS = CDec(Replace(Split(Split(ValueSSH, ",")(14).ToString, "=")(1), ".", ".")) / 1000
                End If
                If Type = "AntMiner L3+" Then
                    ValueGHS = CDec(Replace(Split(Split(ValueSSH, ",")(14).ToString, "=")(1), ".", "."))
                End If
            End If


            If Language = "fr-CA" Then
                If Type = "AntMiner S9" Then
                    ValueGHSM = CDec(Replace(Split(Split(ValueSSH, ",")(15).ToString, "=")(1), ".", ",")) / 1000
                End If
                If Type = "AntMiner L3+" Then
                    ValueGHSM = CDec(Replace(Split(Split(ValueSSH, ",")(15).ToString, "=")(1), ".", ","))
                End If
            Else
                If Type = "AntMiner S9" Then
                    ValueGHSM = CDec(Replace(Split(Split(ValueSSH, ",")(15).ToString, "=")(1), ".", ".")) / 1000
                End If
                If Type = "AntMiner L3+" Then
                    ValueGHSM = CDec(Replace(Split(Split(ValueSSH, ",")(15).ToString, "=")(1), ".", "."))
                End If
            End If

            If ValueGHS > 0 Then
                MS = "Mining"
            Else
                MS = "Problems"
            End If
            ValueGHSDIFF = ValueGHSM - ValueGHS

            GH = Format(ValueGHS, "0.00")
            GHS = Format(ValueGHSM, "0.00")
            If Language = "fr-CA" Then
                ValueReboot = "0,5"
            Else
                ValueReboot = "0.5"
            End If
            If ValueGHSDIFF > ValueReboot Then
                SSHReboot(ip)
                PutDataInTable(IndexOfTable, ip, "0", "0.00", "0.00", "0", "0", "0", "0", "N/D", "Rebooting GH Low", Type, "", "", "0")
                clientssh.Disconnect()
            clientssh = Nothing

            Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(5000)

            GoTo RestartF
            End If
        End If


repprogress:

        PutDataInTable(IndexOfTable, ip, ValueTemp, GH, GHS, Accepteds, Rejects, Discarded, Hwerror, "N/D", MS, Type, ValueSSH, ValueSSHsummary, "0")

nextminer:


    Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(5000)

    cmd = Nothing
        tview = ""
        ValueSSH = ""
        ValueSSHsummary = ""
        Accepteds = ""
        Rejects = ""
        Hwerror = ""
        Discarded = ""
        ValueTemp = ""
        IndexOfTable = 0
        MS = ""
        GH = ""
        GHS = ""
        ValueGHSDIFF = 0
        ValueGHSM = ""
        NBV = 0
        nbvt = 0
        TT = ""
        NBI = 0


    GoTo RestartF


Private Sub PutDataInTable(ByVal LineRendu As Integer, ByVal Ip As String, ByVal Temp As String, ByVal Gh As String, ByVal GHA As String, ByVal Accept As String, ByVal reject As String, ByVal discard As String, ByVal HWE As String, ByVal ps As String, ByVal ms As String, ByVal Type As String, ByVal lastvaluessh As String, ByVal lastvaluesshsummary As String, ByVal howmanystate As String)

    SyncLock DataGridView1

        Dim NBRow As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount
        Dim RowRendu As Integer = 0
        Dim IndexTable As Integer

        Do Until RowRendu > NBRow
            If DataGridView1.Rows(RowRendu).Cells(0).Value = Ip Then
                GoTo EndSearchIndex
            End If
            RowRendu = RowRendu + 1
        Loop
EndSearchIndex:

        DataGridView1.Rows(RowRendu).Cells(1).Value = Temp & " C"
        DataGridView1.Rows(RowRendu).Cells(2).Value = Gh
        DataGridView1.Rows(RowRendu).Cells(3).Value = GHA
        DataGridView1.Rows(RowRendu).Cells(4).Value = Accept
        DataGridView1.Rows(RowRendu).Cells(5).Value = reject
        DataGridView1.Rows(RowRendu).Cells(6).Value = discard
        DataGridView1.Rows(RowRendu).Cells(7).Value = HWE
        DataGridView1.Rows(RowRendu).Cells(9).Value = ms
        DataGridView1.Rows(RowRendu).Cells(10).Value = Type
        DataGridView1.Rows(RowRendu).Cells(11).Value = lastvaluessh
        DataGridView1.Rows(RowRendu).Cells(12).Value = lastvaluesshsummary
        DataGridView1.Rows(RowRendu).Cells(13).Value = 0

    End SyncLock
```

and memmory grow up slowly ... i dont found why ... anyone have a idea whats wrong in my code ?

Comment: You can try garbage collection  before a new run https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Use the diagnotic tools in VS to take a snapshot of all the in-memory objects at start-up, and then take another after the memory usage goes up, and then use the tools to compare the differences.  If you sort it by the change-in-total-object-count column and look at just the objects of classes in your own namespaces (ignoring all the system ones), then the offender is usually pretty close to the top of that list.

Comment: Go To is only in the language for backward compatibility. Please don't use in new code.

Comment: i have take a screen shop via diag and was string builder queue byte and rencii.sshcommand they take all

Comment: nbk you mean gc.collect ?

Comment: yes, such small memory leaks occur, because windows doesn't get rid of it fast enough. follow simply the Link

Comment: i have do lot of test all the night long and change lot of code like mary say no goto, implement gc.collect nothing have work ... i found the problem was leaving open the connection the connection dont flush lot of byte and string ... the only way i found for release it was close the connection ... but if i close it the time for refresh come with a lag ... i dont know what i will do change the library or try to flush the info keeped on it but i really dont know how at this time

Comment: the only thing i dont have try its implement a streamreader and streamwritter and fush it maybe its will work

Comment: @Mary Absolutely not, it's something that should be used rarely (there's almost always a better option), but there are cases where a well-used `GoTo` produces significantly cleaner and more readable code than any of the other built-in language features.  (This most often indicates that there is a missing control keyword that would replace the `GoTo`.)

Comment: @Craig From MS docs "GoTo statements can make code difficult to read and maintain. Whenever possible, use a control structure instead."

Comment: @Mary I don't disagree, I just take issue with "only for backward compatibility" which implies "never".  I don't think either is true.  I agree that it's very rare, and I would give the same advice as the MS docs (in fact, I think that's basically what I said in my comment---there's almost always a better option).

Comment: @Craig Got it! Thank you Craig for the correction.